# Issue on Git Ext for VS 2015

Tags: git, github

[image]
[image]

How can i get these same thing when i right-Click in VS 2015.

Can anyone help me

Right click

Comment: not all of us have access to hosted image sites.  can you please embed your image or give us a description of what it shows?

Comment: When i right click : I was getting GitEXT:Diff  GitEXT:File History GitEXT:Reset File changes in vs 2013 

Thats not coming in VS2015. How to fix it @devlin

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download and install the [context add-on](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35c2f314-a6ab-479a-b4a3-cff99103d32f?SRC=VSIDE).  Please note the prerequisites:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> GitExtensions must be installed for this extension to run properly.
>
> http://gitextensions.github.io

**Side Note:** There is also a [GitHub extension](https://visualstudio.github.com/) for VS 2015 that allows you to interface in much the same way as you would with Team Foundation Server.